# Ajax event executing multiple times - weird behaviour

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#myModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
       $(".save_profile_name").click(function(){
          var pro_id          = $("#profile_id").val();
          var pro_name        = $("#profile_name").val();
          var pro_description = $("#profile_description").val();
          if (pro_id != ""){  
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "myURL",
                    data: { 
                            pro_id: pro_id,
                            pro_name: pro_name,
                            pro_description: pro_description
                          }
               }).done(function( json ) {
                  $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
               });
           }else{ 
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "myURL",
                    data: { 
                            pro_id: pro_id,
                            pro_name: pro_name,
                            pro_description: pro_description
                          }
               }) .done(function( event ) {
                    $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
               });
           }
       });
   });
```

I have an modal from boostrap with a form, which do an insert or an update in db. It works fine, BUT my problem is when I add a new item in db through ajax, after that when I want to add another item, somehow it inserts in db the same **item** two times, after that I add another item, it inserts in db the same **item** 3 times, ... 4 times .... and the cycle repeats. But If I  refreshed the page after the ajax event, it works fine. Can someone help with this ?

Comment: If I put an alert().  inside the $(".save_profile_name").click(function(){ )} , after ajax event it shows 1 time, after another ajax events its shows up 2times, after anothr ajax it shows up 3 times, BUT after refresh only 1 time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have the same ajax call in both if and else clauses?

Answer (score 2):

At a guess I'd say your on-click event is probably firing more than once, because it's getting bound to the elements multiple times in a chain.

I'd suggest pulling out your ajax code into a separate function, and then calling .unbind.bind, to make sure the handler is only called once, something like so:

```
    var handleProfileClick = function() {
        var pro_id          = $("#profile_id").val();
        var pro_name        = $("#profile_name").val();
        var pro_description = $("#profile_description").val();
        if (pro_id != ""){  
             $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "myURL",
                  data: { 
                          pro_id   : pro_id,
                          pro_name : pro_name,
                          pro_description : pro_description
                        }
             }).done(function( json ) {
                $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
             });
         }else{ 
             $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "myURL",
                  data: { 
                            pro_id   : pro_id,
                            pro_name : pro_name,
                            pro_description : pro_description
                        }
             }) .done(function( event ) {
                  $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
             });
         }

    }

    var  handleModalShow = function(event) {
        // do anything else you need here, or just delete the function
    }
    $('#myModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
        handleModalShow();
    });
   $("#myModal1 .save_profile_name").unbind('click', handleProfileClick).bind('click', handleProfileClick)
```

Comment: the modal shows but the onclick it does not work, the console from firebug shows me no errors, no function executed. I copy pasted your code

Comment: I change the click event in my code with this : $(".save_profile_name").unbind('click').bind('click', function () {, It works, BUT another problem occured, If i press my button multiple times, my script executed multiple times now

Comment: You probably don't need to attach the submit handler whenever the modal is shown, since you're not adding/removing that form. I've updated my answer to reflect that, see if that helps (sorry, I just rearranged the code off the top of my head, without actually running it, since I don't have your page structure)